# Difference of values based on the condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two columns which has time and status values. I have to get the difference between the rows of time when the value of status changes from first occurrence of 1 to first occurence of 0.

```
time              status
01-07-2019 13:24    1
02-07-2019 04:02    1
02-07-2019 04:17    0
02-07-2019 04:21    1
02-07-2019 04:35    0
02-07-2019 04:36    1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
if (df1['status'] == 1)
     df1['time_diff'] = df1['time'].sub(df1['time'], axis = 0) 
     print(df1)
```

Comment: Don't post images, provide data in text so other can easily reproduce it

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I have changed the image to text

Comment: @FRECEENAFRANCIS add expected output too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
holder = ''
holding = False

for index, row in df.iterrows(): #Iterrating through each row of the dataframe
    if row['status'] == 1:
        if holding == True:
            continue # Continue to next row if status is 1.
        else
            holder = row['time']
            holding = True # Hold the first timestamp that the loop reads'
            continue
    elif row['status']  == 0
        if holding == True:
            print(row['time'] - holding) # Subtract the timestamp of the first occurence of 0 to the holded timestamp
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Up to you to make some changes to this loop if you want to get every difference each time 1 changes to 0 and store the outputs in a list or whatever you want. I just made it so it computes the first occurence of 1 changing to 0. Just make sure that the data type of the time column is datetime.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How could we extend to get every difference each time 1 changes to 0 and store the outputs in another column in dataframe.

Comment: You'll just need to add another condition that changes holding to False again in order for this loop to get each difference. 

For adding the outputs in a dataframe, I recommend creating an empty list then appending the outputs in that list for every loop iteration then add the list in the dataframe. Please try it out, I already gave the framework for the problem, you just need to add conditions.

Answer (score 0):

First let's make sure the time column is datetime type:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

diff = ['0 days 00:00:00']#first value,has nothing to compare
```

Then, we can access index and data column at the same time, using zip:

```
for st,i in zip(df['status'],df.index):

    if i > 0:#cannot evaluate previous from index 0

        if df['status'][i] != df['status'][i-1]: #current row and previous row

            #print(df['time'][i] - df['time'][i-1])

            diff.append(df['time'][i] - df['time'][i-1])

        else:   

            diff.append('0 days 00:00:00') #no change in status
```

Now, adding the diff list with time differences. Notice, I don't know how you want to handle the 'no change in status' cases.
I assume it would be 0 time difference.

```
df['dif_time'] = diff   

print(df)

             time           status dif_time
0 2019-01-07 13:24:00       1       00:00:00
1 2019-02-07 04:02:00       1       00:00:00
2 2019-02-07 04:17:00       0       00:15:00
3 2019-02-07 04:21:00       1       00:04:00
4 2019-02-07 04:35:00       0       00:14:00
5 2019-02-07 04:36:00       1       00:01:00
```